# Quickest way to check if 10 integers have changed from last cycle

Tags: computer-science, plc

This is a PLC program so the values can change without knowledge.  can someone think of a hash algo that will check if 5 to 10 integers have changed since last cycle.  I need this to be as fast as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just check them against a copy of the previous set of values?

The effort to simply check all 10 is linear, small and constant.  It is unlikely that a hash function would be faster  (you can't avoid reading the values, and that's pretty much all the work required to do a compare), and even it were, having the same hash code doesn't tell you the values haven't changed, so you *still* have to compare all 10 sometimes.

If getting the answer wrong occasionally is OK, you could just XOR all ten values (assumed to be modest size binary integers) for a hashcode, and check against that.  That would avoid reading the old/new values, cutting the read count in half.  Given all the other work the PLC is doing, I doubt if this savings is anything other than nanoscopic.

Comment: That's what I figured need it to run milliseconds quick.  because of a design constant. thanks though

Comment: @mrebus: There are millions of cycles in a millisecond on a single core of a modern computer. If the integers are in the L1 cache this would take less than 0.0001 milliseconds.

Comment: @Charles I need it for a PLC Program I am writing. the PLC program take 10-100 ms to run(yeah thats shitty but I didn't write it).  I need something fast that I can check more often than the main loop runs.  cause I need faster timing on a small piece of code.

Comment: @mrebus: Do you have an operation faster than equality on the PLC?

Comment: @Charles no I went with equality. it was a question as I was trying to build it for a Report By Exception communication module that I was going to generalize.